# Jquery Plugin qTip2 is this what is use on Hypem.com?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-audio

If you go to this website you will notice http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/ qTip2 Jquery Plug (the green template theme) .. It is a project called qTip2 Jquery Plugin.  It looks similar to http://hypem.com/ Jquery.

Is this what they used for audio player  located on top.  It looks like they used this Jquery and and implemented JavaScript into qTip2.  I was looking to do something similar I noticed that there is 22 JavaScript, 2 CSS, 2 PHP and HTML.   One reason to successfully code this, is because trying to achieve a player that hovers above  and users can browse around the site and their music is not interrupted. I seen it done with I-frames but that is not going to be acceptable.  If you have an Ajax example that would be terrific.  I can't find any useful resources relating to an Ajax MP3 player that could be on the top panel.  Do you think this will work , am I on the right track?

If you could please provide source code  or any resources I would greatly appreciate. Thank you

Comment: "I can't find any useful resources relating to an Ajax MP3 player that could be on the top panel." – that's because nobody on the internet will be doing all your work for you. You'll need to look up doing the AJAX navigation, the UI you want, and playing sound from HTML, and figure out how to put them together yourself.

Comment: For what it's worth, Hypem doesn't seem to be using gTip2; the music player popup probably isn't done with any tooltip library. Not even the green top menu on the gTip website is done with gTip itself.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what it is found in and then for the Ajax example why would like to see is a blank to an example of an existing Ajax player

Comment: The answer is no, they don't use qTip2 for the audio player. Take a look at html5's <audio> functionality.

Comment: They don't use any jQuery for the hover effect.  They are using :hover on a parent container that displays the child container in CSS.  The actual MP3 player is most like javascript or HTML driven.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use html5 https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js that can then have your player in fixed position block element.